# Show network folder icon in listview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, listview, shell32.dll

how do I show network folder icon in a listview? the one with the green tube under the folder, I have the code that works great with files and folders but when visiting other computer through network, I can't see the network folders that looks like this one.

[image]

what should I add?

here's my code:
this is how I display icon in a `ListView`

```
Dim fPath As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(fPath)

  ' store imagelist index for known/found file types
  Dim exts As New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)

  If di.Exists = True Then
      Dim img As Image
      Dim lvi As ListViewItem
      For Each d In di.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
          lvi = New ListViewItem(d.Name)
          lvi.SubItems.Add("")
          lvi.SubItems.Add(d.CreationTime.Date)

          ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

          img = NativeMethods.GetShellIcon(d.FullName)
          ImageList1.Images.Add(img)
          lvi.ImageIndex = ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
      Next
```

this is how I get icons from shell32.

```
Partial Public Class NativeMethods
Private Const MAX_PATH As Integer = 256
Private Const NAMESIZE As Integer = 80
Private Const SHGFI_ICON As Int32 = &H100
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure SHFILEINFO
        Public hIcon As IntPtr
        Public iIcon As Integer
        Public dwAttributes As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=MAX_PATH)>
        Public szDisplayName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=NAMESIZE)>
        Public szTypeName As String
    End Structure
    <DllImport("Shell32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SHGetFileInfo(ByVal pszPath As String,
                                      ByVal dwFileAttributes As Integer,
                                      ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO,
                                      ByVal cbFileInfo As Integer,
                                      ByVal uFlags As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function DestroyIcon(ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
    Public Shared Function GetShellIcon(ByVal path As String) As Bitmap
        Dim shfi As SHFILEINFO = New SHFILEINFO()
        Dim ret As IntPtr = SHGetFileInfo(path, 0, shfi, Marshal.SizeOf(shfi), SHGFI_ICON)
        If ret <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Dim bmp As Bitmap = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).ToBitmap
            DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon)
            Return bmp
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get that icon from `Shell32` as a small or large image.  As Cody Gray points out in a comment, there are more icons (200+) in "imageres.dll".  To get these by index, add this method to your `NativeMethods` class:

```vb
<DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function ExtractIconEx(szFileName As String,
                            nIconIndex As Integer,
                            ByRef phiconLarge As IntPtr,
                            ByRef phiconSmall As IntPtr,
                            nIcons As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function

Private Shared ImgResFile As String = "imageres.dll"
Private Shared ShellFile As String = "shell32.dll"

Friend Shared Function GetShellIconByIndex(ndx As Int32,
                         largeIcon As Boolean = False,
                         Optional FromShell As Boolean = True) As Bitmap
    Dim largeIco As IntPtr
    Dim smallIco As IntPtr
    Dim thisIco As IntPtr
    Dim ico As Icon
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = Nothing

    Dim targtFile = If(FromShell, ShellFile, ImgResFile)
    ExtractIconEx(targtFile, ndx, largeIco, smallIco, 1)

    Try
        If largeIcon Then
            ico = Icon.FromHandle(largeIco)
            thisIco = largeIco
        Else
            ico = Icon.FromHandle(smallIco)
            thisIco = smallIco
        End If
        bmp = ico.ToBitmap()
    Catch ex As Exception           ' swallow exception to return nothing
        ' really stupid index values can throw ArgumentException
        ' when the result is IntPtr.Zero
        ' Rather than test it, catch it an any other(s)
    Finally
        DestroyIcon(thisIco)
    End Try

    Return bmp
End Function
```

The first argument is the index of the icon to get, the second indicates whether you want the large or small version, the last is an optional flag to fetch from `imageres.dll` versus `shell32.dll`. Note that the method can result `Nothing` if something goes wrong.

Then modify your folders loop to get the pipe-folder image (#275) from `shell32.dll` when you detect a network drive:

```vb
For Each d In di.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    ...
    If IsNetworkFolder(d) Then
        ' get #275 as small image from Shell 
        img = NativeMethods.GetShellIconByIndex(275, False)
        If img Is Nothing Then
            ' ToDo: perhaps load a default image from Resources?
        End If
    Else
        img = NativeMethods.GetShellIcon(d.FullName)
        If img Is Nothing Then
            img = IconFromFile(d.FullName)
        End If
    End If
    '... add code 
Next

Private Function IsNetworkFolder(di As DirectoryInfo) As Boolean
    Dim drv As New DriveInfo(di.Root.Name)
    Return (drv.DriveType = DriveType.Network)
End Function
```

This uses a helper function to determine whether the folder is networked or not.  If it is, it fetches that specific folder icon, which is #275, from the DLL.  Result:

[image]

That same folder image is also in `imageres.dll` as #137 (and #68 and #69 are similar with world overlays).  To get from that instead:

```vb
'  137 is the index, false for large icon, false to use imageres instead: 
img = NativeMethods.GetShellIconByIndex(137, False, False)
```

If you want to avoid *Magic Numbers* in your code, use constants or an enum of the icons used.  You *could* define them all in the `NativeMethods` class, but that is 500 items and you may well not recall what they mean 6 months later:

```vb
Private Enum ShellIcons
    NetworkFolder1 = 275
    NetworkFolder2 = 103
    SharedFolder = 158
    AddNetworkFolder = 278
End Enum
...
img = NativeMethods.GetShellIconByIndex(ShellIcons.NetworkFolder1, False)
```

---

This will display the icons stored in `shell32.dll` and their index to a `Listview` set to `LargeIcon` View so you can browse them:

```vb
Dim ndx As Int32 = 0
Dim img As Image = Nothing
Dim lvi As ListViewItem

Do
    ' change second Bool to False to get the ones in imageres.dll
    img = NativeMethods.GetShellIconByIndex(ndx, True, True)

    If img IsNot Nothing Then
        lvi = New ListViewItem(ndx.ToString)

        ImageList1.Images.Add(img)
        lvi.ImageIndex = ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
        myLV.Items.Add(lvi)
        ndx += 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop Until img Is Nothing
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the `moricons.dll` icons are very old, the DLL hasn't been updated since the 16-bit Windows days. But you can find lots of new icons used by modern versions of the shell in `imageres.dll`.

Comment: Yea, I knew moricons was very (very) old, I was wondering if there was a newer version of it.  I didnt know about `imageres.dll`, thanks!

Comment: Regarding the code for the first function, I'm not sure why you're worried about exceptions, but if either the `FromHandle` or `ToBitmap` functions were to throw, you would leak the icon handle. You would need to call `DestroyIcon` in a `finally` block.

Comment: MSDN/Object Browser dont mention an exception, but a Try was easier/faster than testing with negative index values etc.  removed it

Comment: Well, negative "index" values are actually allowed for ExtractIconEx. It interprets negative values as specifying the actual resource ID of the icon. The function's interface [is complicated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100505-00/?p=14153). You're doing it correctly, though. If you want to look up by zero-based index, you use a positive integer.